# Are there any studies on the health impact of concrete dust from warfare in an urban setting?

Tags: reference-request, environmental-conditions

Concrete dust is a well known health hazard, [requiring](https://blogs.cdc.gov/niosh-science-blog/2020/08/17/respirators-construction/) a respirator in normal work. But often bombarded cities look like this:

[image]

(Photo credit: BBC.)

Are there any studies on the impact of concrete dust on people in such an environment (I mean separately from other issues), either civilian or military (although preferably the former)? I did a bit of searching, but turned up nothing.

Comment: The WTC attacks might yield more data. A lot of the workers at that site were sickened and many died in ensuing years, including one I knew personally.

Comment: @CareyGregory: good point, but I think those buildings were more 'high tech' and used little concrete. Steel structure etc. Actually, I was partly wrong "floors consisted of 4-inch (10 cm) thick lightweight concrete slabs laid on a fluted steel deck". So there was a fair bit of concrete.

Comment: I visited the site about a month after the attack with that friend who later died. There was abundant concrete and concrete dust. By that time the construction workers were mostly wearing respirators but the first responders didn't, and they spent weeks on site while it was still hot. There's plenty of literature on sarcoidosis and dust exposure, and sarcoidosis killed a lot of them.

Comment: @CareyGregory: thanks for the keyword. I managed to find a paper about that https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29066387/

Comment: @Fizz Steel construction is often primarily concrete, neither material is good for large buildings on its own.